# What does 'practice' mean in 'practice law'? Is it a common to use like this?

Tags: meaning

What does 'practice' mean in 'practice law'? Is it common to use like this?

Comment: Please provide the whole sentence. "Practice" can be a verb or an adjective here, depending on the context. I think it's a verb.

Answer (score 1):

To **practice X** means to engage routinely in activities related to X.

X can be an avocation or activity (snowboarding tricks, tennis, yoga, meditation) or it can be a vocation or profession, like law or medicine, in which case the phrase takes on the meaning "to do things related to X routinely as one's job".